# How to serialize Python objects in a human-readable format?

Tags: python, serialization

I need to store Python structures made of lists / dictionaries, tuples into a human-readable format. The idea is like using something similar to [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html), but pickle is not human-friendly. Other options that come to my mind are [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) (through [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) and [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (through [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/)) serializers.

Any other option that comes to your mind?

Comment: Serialization means you can reinstantiate with saved output, which most of the answers don't show. You are asking for readable serialization for built-in types specifically which is easier. Serialize your variables using `repr()`, and load them back in with *ast.literal_eval*. Eg a quick test you can do is `import ast; ast.literal_eval(repr(myvariable))`, for say `myvariable=(1,2,3)`. If your lists/dictionaries/tuples contain non-built-in types, the logical thing to do is just save them in a readable *.py* module that defines the type and loads values, as you also need the type implementation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For simple cases pprint() and eval() come to mind.

Using your example:

```
>>> d = {'age': 27,
...  'name': 'Joe',
...  'numbers': [1, 
...              2, 
...              3,
...              4,
...              5],
...  'subdict': {
...              'first': 1, 
...              'second': 2,
...               'third': 3
...              }
... }
>>> 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(d)
{'age': 27,
 'name': 'Joe',
 'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'subdict': {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}}
>>>
```

I would think twice about fixing two requirements with the same tool. Have you considered using pickle for the serializing and then pprint() (or a more fancy object viewer) for humans looking at the objects?

Comment: Well, i have to store those structures into files, so they're mainly for the program to load / save them, but i want them to be editable / readable by human beings as well.

Answer (score 15):

If its **just** Python list, dictionary and tuple object. - **JSON** is the way to go. Its human readable, very easy to handle and language independent too.

Caution: Tuples will be converted to lists in simplejson.

```
In [109]: simplejson.loads(simplejson.dumps({'d':(12,3,4,4,5)}))
Out[109]: {u'd': [12, 3, 4, 4, 5]}
```

Comment: New in version 2.2.0 - tuple_as_array flag to change how simplejson handles tuples.  See http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#encoders-and-decoders, and original changes at https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson/pull/6.  This allows one to preserve the difference between tuples and lists.

Answer (score 8):

You should check out jsonpickle (https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle).  It will write out any python object into a json file.  You can then read that file back into a python object.  The nice thing is the inbetween file is very readable because it's json.

Comment: jsonpickle has moved to https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle, do you still recommend using it today ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're after more representations than are covered by JSON, I highly recommend checking out [PyON](http://code.google.com/p/pyon/wiki/GettingStarted) (Python Object Notation)...although I believe it's restricted to 2.6/3.0 and above, as it relies on the **ast** module. It handles custom class instances and recursive data types, amongst other features, which is more than is provided by JSON.

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean this is not human-readable??? ;)

```
>>> d = {'age': 27, 
...   'name': 'Joe',
...   'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5],
...   'subdict': {'first':1, 'second':2, 'third':3}
... }
>>> 
>>> import pickle
>>> p = pickle.dumps(d)      
>>> p
"(dp0\nS'age'\np1\nI27\nsS'subdict'\np2\n(dp3\nS'second'\np4\nI2\nsS'third'\np5\nI3\nsS'first'\np6\nI1\nssS'name'\np7\nS'Joe'\np8\nsS'numbers'\np9\n(lp10\nI1\naI2\naI3\naI4\naI5\nas."
```

Ok, well, maybe it just takes some practice… or you could cheat...

```
>>> import pickletools 
>>> pickletools.dis(p)
    0: (    MARK
    1: d        DICT       (MARK at 0)
    2: p    PUT        0
    5: S    STRING     'age'
   12: p    PUT        1
   15: I    INT        27
   19: s    SETITEM
   20: S    STRING     'subdict'
   31: p    PUT        2
   34: (    MARK
   35: d        DICT       (MARK at 34)
   36: p    PUT        3
   39: S    STRING     'second'
   49: p    PUT        4
   52: I    INT        2
   55: s    SETITEM
   56: S    STRING     'third'
   65: p    PUT        5
   68: I    INT        3
   71: s    SETITEM
   72: S    STRING     'first'
   81: p    PUT        6
   84: I    INT        1
   87: s    SETITEM
   88: s    SETITEM
   89: S    STRING     'name'
   97: p    PUT        7
  100: S    STRING     'Joe'
  107: p    PUT        8
  110: s    SETITEM
  111: S    STRING     'numbers'
  122: p    PUT        9
  125: (    MARK
  126: l        LIST       (MARK at 125)
  127: p    PUT        10
  131: I    INT        1
  134: a    APPEND
  135: I    INT        2
  138: a    APPEND
  139: I    INT        3
  142: a    APPEND
  143: I    INT        4
  146: a    APPEND
  147: I    INT        5
  150: a    APPEND
  151: s    SETITEM
  152: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 0
>>>
```

You'd still have to read the pickled object from a file, however you wouldn't need to `load` it.  So, if it's a "dangerous" object, you still might be able to figure that out before doing the `load`.  If you are stuck with a `pickle`, it might be a good option for deciphering what you have.

Answer (score 2):

To use simplejson first **easy_install simplejson**:

```
import simplejson
my_structure = {"name":"Joe", "age":27, "numbers":[1,2,3,4,5], "subdict":{"first":1, "second":2, "third": 3}}
json = simplejson.dumps(my_structure)
```

results in json being:

```
{"age": 27, "subdict": {"second": 2, "third": 3, "first": 1}, "name": "Joe", "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

Notice that its hardly changed the format of the dictionary at all, but you should run it through this step to ensure valid JSON data.

You can further pretty print the result:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(my_structure)
```

results in:

```
{'age': 27,
 'name': 'Joe',
 'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'subdict': {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [AXON](https://intellimath.bitbucket.io/axon) (textual) format that combine the **best** of JSON, XML and YAML. 
AXON format is quite readable and relatively compact.

The python (2.7/3.3-3.7) module [pyaxon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyaxon) supports `load(s)`/`dump(s)` functionality, including iterative `loading`/`dumping`. It's sufficiently fast in order to be useful.

Consider simple example:

```
>>> d = {
     'age': 27, 'name': 'Joe', 
     'numbers': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
     'subdict': {'first': 1, 'second': 2, 'third': 3}
    }
# pretty form
>>> axon.dumps(d, pretty=1)
{ age: 27
  name: "Joe"
  numbers: [1 2 3 4 5]
  subdict: {
    first: 1
    second: 2
    third: 3}}
# compact form
>>> axon.dumps(d)
{age:27 name:"Joe" numbers:[1 2 3 4 5] subdict:{first:1 second:2 third:3}}
```

It also can handle multiple objects in the message:

```
>>> msg = axon.dumps([{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':4}])
>>> print(msg)
{a:1 b:2 c:3} 
{a:2 b:3 c:4}
{a:3 b:4 c:5}
```

and then load them iteratively:

```
for d in axon.iloads(msg):
   print(d)
```

Comment: Bitbucket links are dead (thanks, atlassian).