# Read list of lists of tuples in Python from file

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I'd like to read and write a list of lists of tuples from and to files.

```
g_faces = [[(3,2)(3,5)],[(2,4)(1,3)(1,3)],[(1,2),(3,4),(6,7)]]
```

I used

- `pickle.dump(g_faces, fp)`
- `pickle.load(fp)`

But the file is not human readable. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: *"the file is not human readable"* - so what? It's not supposed to be.

Comment: you could use `json` which uses the same interface or `eval` if you're brave. You'll have to compromise on the format a bit if you're using `json`.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Python human readable object serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408866/python-human-readable-object-serialization?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the json module.

```
import json

g_faces = [[(3,2), (3,5)],[(2,4), (1,3), (1,3)],[(1,2), (3,4), (6,7)]]

json.dump(g_faces, open('test.json', 'w'))

g_faces = json.load(open('test.json'))

# cast back to tuples
g_faces = [[tuple(l) for l in L] for L in g_faces]
```

Comment: Note that JSON can't distinguish between lists and tuples (both are serialized as a JSON array), so the result will contain *all* lists.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point. The OP is asking for a list of tuples.

Comment: It tells me: TypeError: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test.json' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'> is not JSON serializable

Comment: @MarioStefanutti I swapped the order of argument in the `dump` method. Code has been corrected.

Comment: Is there a way to make it read the inner elements as tuples instead of lists?

Comment: @MarioStefanutti You could cast it into a tuple after you read it. As noted above, `json` will always cast the tuples as lists.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'm going to do like this. But do you know why JSON can't distinguish between lists and tuples. Is there a reason or limitation?

Comment: @MarioStefanutti Likely because JSON is used to move data between systems and languages. Not all languages implement tuples. My guess.