# Reading data from text turns into list of lines

Tags: python

I have some data in python as an array as follows :

```
train = [("Great place to be when you are in Bangalore.", "pos"),
  ("The place was being renovated when I visited so the seating was limited.", "neg"),
  ("Loved the ambience, loved the food", "pos"),
  ("The food is delicious but not over the top.", "neg"),
  ("Service - Little slow, probably because too many people.", "neg"),
  ("The place is not easy to locate", "neg"),
  ("Mushroom fried rice was spicy", "pos"),
  ("Cocee was hot and spicy", "neg")
]
```

I want to read this data from a file. So I created a text file and copied the data into it.

Now when I read from the text file using below code :

```
train = []
text_file = open("testdata.txt", "r")
train = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()
```

the `train` is having 8 items splitted by each line in the text document. I want it as the same data I am giving in python code. Please help. The mentioned duplicate question did not answer mine.

Comment: save it in another py file and import it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read list of lists of tuples in Python from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40074923/read-list-of-lists-of-tuples-in-python-from-file)

Comment: ... <hidden> ...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : Sorry I am new to python. Please help. i did not get u

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ : That did the trick man. Thanks. Sorry if I asked a very simple doubt here.

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Use the `ast` module

```
import ast
text_file = open("testdata.txt", "r")
train = text_file.read()
text_file.close()

print(ast.literal_eval(train.replace("train = ", "")))
```

**Output:**

```
[('Great place to be when you are in Bangalore.', 'pos'), ('The place was being renovated when I visited so the seating was limited.', 'neg'), ('Loved the ambience, loved the food', 'pos'), ('The food is delicious but not over the top.', 'neg'), ('Service - Little slow, probably because too many people.', 'neg'), ('The place is not easy to locate', 'neg'), ('Mushroom fried rice was spicy', 'pos'), ('Cocee was hot and spicy', 'neg')]
```

Answer (score -1):

use the json library

```
# reading
with open('dump.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = [tuple(x) for x in json.load(f)]

# writing
with open('dump.txt', 'w') as f:
    a = json.dump(f)
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter. json.load(f) is not working since it is text file. @A.Bau