# To save objects in a file without use binary serialization, Python 3.7.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, serialization

I use Python 3.7.1.

What I am looking for is to save transformed/treated object in a file, then open this file in a **any** text editor.

`JSON` is not what I am looking for. ["`JSON` is a text serialization format (it outputs unicode text, although most of the time it is then encoded to utf-8), while `pickle` is a binary serialization format"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#comparison-with-json). It looks perfect but my problem is `JSON` has no reason to support a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) object. As far as I know it supports `dict`,`list`,and so on, but not this kind of objects.

Besides, as you read `pickle` makes binary serialization and this is unreadable by **any** text editor.

So, I want to know if there are other ways of human readable serialization of python's object, hoping this is not to complicated to implement.

Comment: I think this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408866/python-human-readable-object-serialization

Comment: More hints : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476983/deserialize-a-json-string-to-an-object-in-python and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906831/serializing-a-python-namedtuple-to-json

Comment: @PilouPili Thank you. The [library shown](https://pypi.org/project/jsonplus/) in the second topic seems alright. I gonna test it.

Comment: Pleasure. If you find something generic and that does the job you can answer your own question to help the community.